# is there any way to use 'ə' letter in input field?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts

I want to write 'Ə' letter on the TMP inputField but it recognize that letter as '?' symbol.And also when I copy and paste that letter to the InputField it works but when I try to insert it from keyboard it does not work. Is there any way to use that letter?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TextMeshPro input field](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html) instead default input field.

This new version includes Dynamic SDF support where it won't be necessary to add the needed characters to the font asset (ahead of time) via the Font Asset Creator. Instead the needed characters / glyphs can be added dynamically to a newly created font asset in the Editor or at Runtime.

You will still need to create a font asset from a font file that contains the Azerbaijanian character set.

Comment: when I copy and paste that letter to the inputField it works but when I try to insert it from keyboard it is not working

Comment: maybe is something related with your keyboard config?

Comment: but I used same keyboard to ask question in stackoverflow and here I used that letter with keyboard